# Create has_and_belongs_to_many and belongs_to both

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have to build functionality where a user create a company and then many user can be associated with that company. It will be simple and can be done by `has_and_belongs_to_many`. But i also have to record and identify the user who has created that company. If you need any other information let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a separate association for the User representing the 'owner' of the Company:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :owned_companies, class_name: 'Company', foreign_key: :owner_id
  has_and_belongs_to_many :companies
end
```

Comment: can i use  has_many :through . i know i can but just want to verify that

Comment: Absolutely!  In fact, you're encouraged to do so.